# Choosing the last element of a list

Tags: list, scala

```
scala> last(List(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8))
res0: Int = 8
```

for having a result above, I wrote this code:

```
val yum = args(0).toInt
val thrill: 

def last(a: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
     println(last(List(args(0).toInt).last)
     }
```

What is the problem with this code?

Comment: Please try to be more precise about what the problem is. Is there a compiler error? Do you mean design issues?

Comment: This code doesn't compile, the line `val thrill:` is meaningless. The `last` definition makes no sense at all. You'd be better off just asking _"how can I get the last element of a list"_ than what you've done here. Honestly, I go to great lengths to answer Scala questions, I edit the questions to make them look better, but the questions about Scala you've posted in the last few days have been awful. Look at other, well-voted, questions to see how to make them.

Answer (score 91):

You can use `last`, which returns the last element or throws a `NoSuchElementException`, if the list is empty.

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3).last
res0: Int = 3
```

If you do not know if the list is empty or not, you may consider using `lastOption`, which returns an `Option`.

```
scala> List().lastOption
res1: Option[Nothing] = None

scala> List(1, 2, 3).lastOption
res2: Option[Int] = Some(3)
```

Your question is about `List`, but using `last` on a infinite collection (e.g. `Stream.from(0)`) can be dangerous and may result in an infinite loop.

Comment: This is actually one of the set of problems from http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/

Simply using .last will defeat the purpose.

Comment: @holyxiaoxin: For people, who actually want to use this, this is the best option.

Comment: Better to use `lastOption` rather than `last`

Answer (score 12):

Another version without using `last` (for whatever reason you might need it).

```
def last(L:List[Int]) = L(L.size-1)
```

Comment: This can be adapted to get the second to last item, which can be very helpful!

Answer (score 9):

You should better do:

```
 val a = List(1,2,3) //your list
 val last = a.reverse.head
```

Cleaner and less error-prone :)

Comment: Has .reverse.head an advantage against .last?

Comment: Not really. It first builds up a new list whereas `last` only "remembers" the last element it touched and checks if there is another one after that.

Comment: This would be a okay in a lazy language like Haskell, but for Scala this is just terrible because of the overhead.

Comment: as far as I remember form the Scala 2.8 book, the list is a linked list, so the head is easily accessible but getting the last elements has linear cost. I'm seeing right now in the book an example recommending reverse.head.

Comment: [List docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) says `prepend()` and `head()` operations are `O(1)`;  `append()`, `reverse()` and `last()` are O(n) of number of elements in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Albiet this is a very old question, it might come handy that the performance impact of head and last operations seems to be laid out here http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html.

Comment: This would have worked better as a comment, @marton, as it doesn't answer the original question directly. Nice info, though! Btw, the given link doesn't mention `last` nor `reverse.head`.

Comment: ...but the [List doc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) does!

Answer (score 0):

The recursive function last should following 2 properties. Your *last* function doesn't have any of them.

- Requirement #1. An exit condition that does not call recursive
  function further.
- Requirement #2. A recursive call that reduces the elements that we began with.

Here are the problems I see with other solutions.

1. Using built in function last might not be an option in interview
   questions.
2. Reversing and head takes additional operations, which the interviewer might ask to reduce.
3. What if this is a custom linked list without the size member?

I will change it to as below.

```
def last(a: List[Int]): Int = a match {
  //The below condition defines an end condition where further recursive calls will not be made. requirement #1
  case x::Nil => x
  //The below condition reduces the data - requirement#2 for a recursive function.
  case x:: xs => last(xs)
}

last(List(1,2,3))
```

Result

```
res0: Int = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

In these types of questions the useful `take` and `takeRight` are often overlooked. Similar to `last`, one avoids the slow initial reversing of a list, but unlike `last`, can take the last (or first) `n` items as opposed to just a single one:

```
scala> val myList = List(1,2,3)
myList: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> myList.takeRight(2)
res0: List[Int] = List(2, 3)

scala> myList.takeRight(1)
res1: List[Int] = List(3)
```